# use highland stream for deferred calcuation

Tags: highland.js

I am trying to use a highland stream to pass back two objects: another data stream and a metadata object. I create the stream:

```
const outputStream = ...;
const hstream = _.([outputStream]);
client.connect( .. function() {
  // fill data stream & also compute metadata, then
  hstream.append(meta);
  hstream.append(_.nil);
});
```

Later I consume this using:

```
hstream.apply(function(dataStream, meta) {
  ...
});
```

The problem is that the function called by apply acts before `hstream` has come to an end, and doesn't see the "meta" object. How can I reconfigure this so that apply is not called until hstream has both objects in it?

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
const outputStream = ...;
const hstream = _.();

client.connect( .. function() {
  // fill data stream & also compute metadata, then:
  ...
  hstream.write(outputStream);
  hstream.write(meta);
  hstream.end();
});
```

In general I find highland streams to be quite powerful and flexible, but the abstraction is not very clear. In the current case there is nothing explicit
in the interface that makes it clear that the first version I wrote considers itself "finished" even though you can call append synchronously. Perhaps more doc and/or explicit options... e.g in the current case:

```
const hstream = _.([outputStream], {lazy: true})
```

(Or something like this...)